# What is the right way to convert a namespaced clojure keyword to string?

Tags: clojure

When the `name` function is used it correctly returns the name of a keyword as a String, as in:

```
(name :k) ; => "k"
```

A problem exists when using `name` on a namespaced keyword such as:

```
(name :n/k) ; => "k"
```

I can use the `namespace` function to correctly obtain the string I'm looking for:

```
(str (namespace :n/k) "/" (name :n/k)) ; => "n/k"
```

But for some reason I feel there should be a better way to obtain the fully qualified string.

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keywords actually store a symbol with the same namespace and name in a public final field and generate their string representations by prepending a colon to the string representation of that symbol. So, we can simply ask the symbol for the same and not prepend the colon:

```
(str (.-sym :foo/bar))
;= "foo/bar"
```

Comment: This approach is a lot faster than `(.substring (str :foo/bar) 1)` for me, 4.7ns vs 14ns.

Comment: For the beauty of code, you can also use the `symbol` function in Clojure 1.11:
`(str (symbol :foo/bar))`.

Answer (score 7):

```
(subs (str :foo/k) 1)
;=> "foo/k"
```

Answer (score 7):

Your approach is the best way to do it; it's only hard because converting a namespaced keyword to a string is an uncommon goal, and not something you'd expect to do regularly. You could write it without repeating the keyword, if you wanted:

```
(string/join "/" ((juxt namespace name) k))
```

Comment: I know, this particular case I had mime types, eg. `:text/plain` that need to be stringified before putting them on the wire. So they're not exactly _clojure_ namespaces

Answer (score 0):

Based on the implementation of `name`:

```
user=> (source name)
(defn name
  "Returns the name String of a string, symbol or keyword."
  {:tag String
   :added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [x]
  (if (string? x) x (. ^clojure.lang.Named x (getName))))
nil
user=>
```

And given that the `clojure.lang.Named` interface has a `getNamespace` method:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Named.java

So you can do this:

```
(defn full-name [k] (str (.getNamespace k) "/" (.getName k)))
```

Comment: What about in clojurescript?

Comment: There are built-inis for this - `(namespace :foo/bar)` -> `"foo"`, and `(name :foo/bar)` -> `"bar"`